# How to list kubernetes services in k9s?

Tags: kubernetes

How can I list the kubernetes services in k9s?

By default only the pods and deployments are shown.

It's possible as shown [here](https://youtu.be/83jYehwlql8?t=70) and I'm using the current k9s version 0.7.11

Comment: k9s is a tool for kubernetes. The tag kubernetes has 17805 questions. So I thought the question fits here.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's documented here:

[**Key Bindings**](https://github.com/derailed/k9s)

> K9s uses aliases to navigate most K8s resources.
>
> :alias View a Kubernetes resource aliases

So you have to type:

```
:svc
```

**EDIT: Hotkeys**

You can also configure custom hotkeys.
Here's my config file ~/.k9s/hotkey.yml
or ~/Library/Application Support/k9s/hotkey.yml

```
hotKey:
  f1:
    shortCut: F1
    description: View pods
    command: pods
  f2:
    shortCut: F2
    description: View deployments
    command: dp
  f3:
    shortCut: F3
    description: View statefulsets
    command: sts
  f4:
    shortCut: F4
    description: View services
    command: service
  f5:
    shortCut: F5
    description: View ingresses
    command: ingress
```

Comment: The file path on linux is currently `~/.config/k9s/hotkey.yml` (or `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/k9s/hotkey.yml`).

Comment: Under Windows it is `%LOCALAPPDATA%\k9s\hotkey.yml`